# How to use Python Cryptography to load a der certificate without backend (or what backend to use)

Tags: python, cryptography, x509, der

For a project I am trying to load and be able to use a certificate (that's already downloaded on the system, name known, der extention confirmed). To accomplish this I am trying to use cryptography (tried it differently but cryptography is a demand made externally).

What I have done so far is follow their own documentation. Namely this:

```
>>> from cryptography import x509
>>> cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(pem_data)
```

I have replaced pem_data with the name of the certificate. If I do this, then I get the following error:

> TypeError: load_der_x509_certificate() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

What I have also done to try and avoid this error is:

```
>>> from cryptography import x509
>>> cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(pem_data, backend=None)
```

However, then I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load_der_x509_certificate'

I suppose None not having a use isn't too surprising, but unfortunately I can not seem to find any indication of what backend I should use anywhere in their documentation. I tried googling it and I found something about Hazmat (cryptography.hazmat.backends.default_backend()) But this comes with warnings not to use it unless I'm sure and seems to be a method, not an actual backend.

Could someone indicate 1: why is this method not working with one argument given when their documentation explicitly states providing a backend is optional and/or 2: What backend can I use to solve the issue?

Comment: The explanation can be found in the [docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/index.html#backends). From 3.1 on the parameter is optional, for this compare also the docs of e.g. [3.2.1](https://cryptography.io/en/3.2.1/x509/reference/) and [3.0](https://cryptography.io/en/3.0/x509/reference/). The backend concept is described [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/interfaces.html#backend-interfaces). In practice I've only seen the use of the `default_backend()`, so I don't think that this concept is really used consequently (but this is only a guess).

Comment: Ah yes. @topaco, thanks. Indeed, somehow I have an older version installed. I will try to install a version where this is not required. Thank you!